# OpenLayers 5: How to import the needed Files in html/js?

Tags: javascript, html, import, openlayers-5

I'm trying to get the basic example of OpenLEayers 5 to work.
This is my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v5.2.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
      slkdj
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script>
      import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
      import View from 'ol/View.js';
      import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile.js';
      import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM.js';


      var map = new Map({
        layers: [
          new TileLayer({
            source: new OSM()
          })
        ],
        target: 'map',
        view: new View({
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 2
        })
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I placed all OpenLayers Files under `./ol/` on my web server. This Folder contains Files like this: `array.js`, `array.js.map`, ..., `Map.js`, `Map.js.map` and so on. I have downloaded the files by running this command: `npm install ol` (Version is 5.2.0).

The web page showes a blank site. What is needed to show the map?

Comment: I think [this (Building an OpenLayers Application)](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/bundle.html) is what you are missing.

Comment: You set some size for the map div in the css.